# Need to set up a phone with limited permissions to help with a learning disorder

Tags: rooting, root-access

I need to set up a phone that will allow the user access to installed apps but will not allow them to install new apps.  In addition I need to allow access to only a whitelist of websites.  These constraints need to be unbreakable short of a factory wipe.  My thought regarding privacy was to have a superuser account that the user and administrator each have half of the password, so the administrator can't get on the phone without the permission of the user.

I'm kind of desperate here.  I asked this question twice on r/androidroot and both times people told me to just install apps that "reward good behavior" etc.  We're way past that point.  The user really needs email, text, maps, and a few work related apps (plus definitely some apps like Habitica to reward good habits!).

I haven't rooted a phone before but am fairly technically proficient.  If Tasker is any part of the solution I'm pretty handy with that, otherwise I will do or learn anything necessary to make this happen.  I have a google pixel to work with but if absolutely necessary will get a different phone.

Thank you very much for any help you're able to provide!
p.s. the disorder is a pretty strong Executive Function disorder - despite 18 years of therapy with 6 different people the user is basically unable to build good habits or demonstrate much willpower.  It's been pretty devastating for them.

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty sad condition you have there, I hope what I am going to provide will be much useful for you.

1. In order to prevent the user from installing new apps from Play Store, you may try any of this method from this article:

   - https://useboomerang.com/2018/07/25/3-ways-block-kids-installing-apps-android-phone/
2. Regarding with allowing only specific websites to access, you can try from any of the followings:

   - https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-block-websites-android-4179021
   - https://techwiser.com/block-websites-on-android/
3. I am not really sure if we are able to set this up, however, try this:

   - https://superuser.com/questions/1156080/how-to-stop-users-from-viewing-saved-passwords-in-chrome

Maybe the link below can be a good addition:
- https://www.howtogeek.com/223530/how-to-lock-down-your-android-tablet-or-smartphone-for-kids/

Comment: Thank you for these - The first article talks about Google Family Link and if it's not easy to defeat that does everything I'm looking for!  It involves me pretending to be ten years old which would've been humiliating a year ago, but now I just care about results.  It's kind of weird, but I don't want to do too much reading about if it can be defeated because I don't want to know how to do it :-)